# Boolean tool trouble with diffence

Tags: boolean-modifier, multiresolution

ive been trying to make a airsoft mask for a few months now but im having trouble finishing the model to export in stl for printing.

i finished sculpting, but now i have to make holes for the horns and hole for the face to fit, as right the only way i was able to sculpt it was on a solid sphere mesh.

evrytime i try to apply the boolean tool on either ti doesnt work, either my pc crashes (i tried lowering the viewport #) but then the boolean doesnt get substracted, it adds the sphere to the sculpt doin the oposite of what i need.

and my due date is now within the next few days, which means i need to print it within the next 2 days.

i just found this site, and now im getting desperate.

[image: how i want the sphere to be applied]

[image: after boolean tool applied on sphere]
[image: the mask sculpted ready to add boolean on horns holes and sphere]

Comment: ive tried uploading my file as well for help but it says its too big, im not sure how to make it smaller. im starting to think im way over my head with this project and program

Comment: try uploading file to dropbox or google drive then publicly share the link

Comment: here is the link to the google drive folder and file.            https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tV5J4huvqa0UT_QIZbkQqjnuy06n5f2E?usp=sharing

Comment: weird why is it so big 1GB for just this model in the screenshot? unfortunately it doesn't open, takes forever to open. Have you tried all the options in *File > Cleanup* to make sure you remove everything that is unnecessary? maybe you included the materials. remove all materials and then *File > Cleanup* and *Save As* another file.

Comment: I will try that and reupload it. Thank you

Comment: Also make sure that *File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources* is __NOT__ checked

Comment: File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources  is NOT checked.        File > Cleanup    it says  <no orphaned data to purge>     i havent added any materials either. im unfortunatly still very new to this. thank you for helping